# document.getElementById injecting Answer from prompt in to wrong place

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

A while ago I found a function (on here) that would allow me to launch a Javascript prompt box on form submit, it would take a value and then submit it alongside the submitted form.

I've been racking my brain as to why this isn't working correctly. At the moment, if I click submit on the form on a row that isn't the very first row in my table, it submits the form on the first row.

The function uses document.getElementById to find where it's entering the entered text but because it's a while loop, document.getElementById("invoiceEntry").value = answer; exists on every row of the table and it injects the text in to the very first instance.

Is there an easy solution to this?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    <script language="Javascript">
    function invoiceCollect() {
      var answer = prompt("Enter invoice number:");
      if(answer) {  // answer = false if "cancel" pressed.
        document.getElementById("invoiceEntry").value = answer;
        return true;
      }
      else if(answer == "") {  // return false if no input entered, i.e. ""
        return false;
    }
      else
        return false;
    }
    </script>

    <form id='invoice' method='post' action='update_item.php'  onsubmit='return invoiceCollect()'>
    <input type='hidden' name='invoiced' >
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['id'] . "' >
    <input type='hidden' name='invoiceNo' id='invoiceEntry' value='' >
    </form>
<input type='submit' value='Invoice' form='invoice'>
```

Comment: give them all different ids.

Comment: @akonsu - Thanks for your reply. Do you mean give the invoiceEntry field a different ID? I could couple it with the $row['id'] so it's unique but how do I then reference that in the JavaScript? Do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that the while loop you're talking about is server side, in PHP and it wraps the HTML you posted. If that is not the case, please comment and i will delete the answer as it would be off-topic.

**Problem 1:**
Your function shouldn't be defined in a loop. You want all your functions to do the same thing, maybe to a different element. A single function with the element as a parameter would be all that's needed.

**Problem 2:**
Identifying the correct element. This is the actual problem you're facing. All your functions use the first element with that ID because that's just how HTML is defined, it expects the IDs to be unique.
The simplest solution is to add the form as parameter to the function:

JavaScript:

```
function invoiceCollect(form) {
  form.invoiceNo.value = 'WORKS';
}
```

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit = 'return invoiceCollect(this)'>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cufanoyu/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

Problem 1: I have defined the script inside the HEAD section - I believe that is correct placement, is that right?

Problem 2: Any chance you could give me some pointers on how to implement that solution please? Does that work alongside the current function?

Comment: No, you don't need the current function.

Comment: Does this need adding to the current function, in that case? I presume the above function isn't going to prompt me for the number?

Comment: OK, found this to be the solution after some playing.

Used the `invoiceCollect(this)` to pass it back to the function.

Now the function is:


`<script language="JavaScript">
function invoiceCollect(form) {
  var answer = prompt("Enter invoice number:");
  if(answer) {  // answer = false if "cancel" pressed.
    form.invoiceNo.value = answer;
    return true;
  }
  else if(answer == "") {  // return false if no input entered, i.e. ""
    return false;
}
  else
    return false;
}
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Make the

```
<input type='submit' value='Invoice' form='invoice'>
```

before the

```
</form>
```

so it would be like this :

```
<script language="Javascript">
function invoiceCollect() {
  var answer = prompt("Enter invoice number:");
  if(answer) {  // answer = false if "cancel" pressed.
    document.getElementById("invoiceEntry").value = answer;
    return true;
  }
  else if(answer == "") {  // return false if no input entered, i.e. ""
    return false;
}
  else
    return false;
}
</script>

<form id='invoice' method='post' action='update_item.php'  onsubmit='return invoiceCollect()'>
<input type='hidden' name='invoiced' >
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['id'] . "' >
<input type='hidden' name='invoiceNo' id='invoiceEntry' value='' >
<input type='submit' value='Invoice' form='invoice'>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. If I do this then I don't see the entry I enter in to the prompt box as it updates the very first row in the table and posts without updating invoiceEntry at all. Unfortunately, it's one of the many things I tried.